# How can I change Scala script's directory?

Tags: scala, directory

I want use Scala like Python, so I install REPL in Sublime Text(Os is win8)

Everytime in REPL, I have to

```
scala> :load <my file>
```

, so I think it's inconvenient.

And I can't change

```
scala> :settings -d <路径名>
```

in Chinese directory.

I'm confused whether I can't change Scala script's directory with non-english language.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) then you can define initial commands when you launch the console.

*yourproject/build.sbt:*

```
// build.sbt

name := "initial-commands-example"

initialCommands := "import Foo._"
```

*yourproject/script.scala:*

```
// script.scala

object Foo {
  def hello(name: String) = s"hello $name"
  val msg = hello("world")
}
```

Inside *yourproject*, run `sbt console`, and you will have everything in `Foo` available inside that repl. See [sbt initialCommands docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/scala.html#initial) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have sloved.